# I am getting StaleElementReferenceException after navigating to different Page and coming back

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting StaleElementReferenceException after navigating to different Page and coming back.I have tried Explicit Wait,re-write the locator again but seems like its not working.Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
    Select selectElement = new Select(dropdown);
    List<WebElement> allOptions=selectElement.getOptions();
    for (WebElement eachElement : allOptions) {  
        System.out.println(eachElement.getText());
        selectElement.selectByVisibleText(eachElement.getText());
        clickElement(selectThisOption);
        enterOnlinePage().dataEntry;
        changeDistrictPage();
        WaitFunctions.waitForPageLoaded(driver);
        new Select(dropdown);
      //Select selectElement = new Select(dropdown);
        allOptions=selectElement.getOptions();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly correct behaviour! Once you navigate anywhere (forward and even back) **all** your WebElements are now stale. You have to change the logic of your loop, something like this:

```
Select selectElement = new Select(dropdown);
int count = selectElement.getOptions().size();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {  
        // must read the element again every time!
        Select selectElement = new Select(dropdown);
        selectElement.selectByIndex(i);

        // the rest of your code ...
}
```